# How to get 'ALTER' in SQL statements when using SMO class in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema, database-schema, smo

I have been looking into the using SMO into trying to create, alter and drop tables/views/stored procedures using similar structure to the code below:

```
if (taskType == TaskType.Alter.ToString())
{
    if (item.SourceResults != null && item.SourceResults != "" && item.SelectionCheckboxProperty == true && item.DatabasePropertyType == DatabasePropertyType.Table)
    {
        sourceConnectionstring = $"server={sourceservername};Database={sourcedatabase};User Id={sourceusername};Password={sourcepassword};Encrypt=False;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=False;";

        using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionstring))
        {
            await sourceConnection.OpenAsync();

            Server sourceserver = new Server(sourceservername);
            Database sourceDataBase = sourceserver.Databases[sourcedatabase];
            Table sourceTable = sourceDatabase.Tables[item.SourceResults];

            Scripter scripter = new Scripter(sourceserver);
            scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = true;  
            scripter.Options.ScriptForCreateOrAlter = true;
            scripter.Options.ScriptForAlter = false;
            scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = true;  
            scripter.Options.ScriptData = false;     

            Urn tableUrn = sourceTable.Urn;

            try
            {
                ScriptDatalabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                StringCollection createScript = scripter.Script(new Urn[] { tableUrn });
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

However, I have been struggling to get 'ALTER' to any table/stored procedure/view as I keep on getting 'CREATE' all the time when I used debug in visual in `createScript`.

I have created code above and results were always create instead of alter when the source and target were identical. (e.g. say if table were identical but target is missing like one or more columns, it will always do create instead of alter).

***Edit1:***

I have tried changing the options into

```
scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = false; 
//scripter.Options.ScriptForCreateOrAlter = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptForAlter = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptData = false;
```

However, my `createScript` is always showing the following:

[image]

that is the only item in the array list. For altering, what would be the best approach for getting alter script? What options should I be using?

***Edit2:***

I have a few extra questions:

- Does the SMO package have this alter feature? If it does, then is there a limitation to it?
- Is there a reason why I would be getting "CREATE" instead "ALTER"?
- Would it be best for me to look into altering Tables/Views/Stored Procedures manually? Like creating If statements and creating Strings based on whether there is a difference (like missing column/s; dropping and/or add/remove foreign keys; etc.).
- Is there a different package that does the same thing as SMO?
- Is there any tutorial/blog/website that would explain how to use the SMO package in C#?
- Is it best to create like WPF application that implements a similar database comparison like in RedGate, etc.. Or Use Visual Studio SQL database project for Schema comparison?

***Edit 3:***

I have tried to add the option EnforceScriptingOptions but it didn't work. Is there another approach to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry if this is an ignorant comment, but could `ScriptForAlter = false;` have something to do with it?

Comment: Hello @500-InternalServerError , if I used `//scripter.Options.ScriptForCreateOrAlter = false; scripter.Options.ScriptForAlter = true;` I keep on getting empty script as `""`

Comment: You're trying to script three types of objects (tables, views, and stored procedures). I'd recommend breaking tables out from the other two as it's different insofar as there's not a single `alter` statement that will completely re-define the object (whereas there is with views and procs). So script the latter two as `create or alter` and then figure out how you want to handle tables.

Comment: @BenThul the script that I show is just part of my script. but overall I already separated SMO for schema to target tables and when it is done it will then target views and after finishing from views it will then go to Stored procedures. The script is similar for views and stored procedure, however, I am still facing the same problem instead of getting the ALTER SQL script I always get CREATE